# @patch mock to mysqldb connection is not working

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, mysql-python, patch

I am writing Unit test for Python app that connects to Mysql using MySQLdb . 
There is a function that connects to Mysql db and returns the connection object.

```
def connect_to_database():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_pb2['mysql_host'],
                          user=db_pb2['mysql_user'],
                          passwd=db_pb2['mysql_password'],
                          db=db_pb2['mysql_db'])
    return conn
```

There is one more function that executes the query using the above connection

```
def execute_query():
    cur = connect_to_database().cursor()
    a = cur.execute("query")
    if a > 0:
        result = cur.fetchall()
    return result
```

I have written @patch to mock the return value from the cur.fetchall() and cur.execute() methods

```
@patch('application.module1.data_adapters.connect_to_database')
def test_daily_test_failures(self, db_connection):
    db_connection.cursor().execute.return_value = 1
    db_connection.cursor().fetchall. \
        return_value = ((1,5,6),)
    self.assertEqual((execute_query(),
                       ((1,5,6),))
```

I get the following error:

```
if a > 0:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'
```

Seems like the return value in patch function is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Your patching requires a bit more effort.

```
@patch('application.module1.data_adapters.connect_to_database')
def test_daily_test_failures(self, connect_to_database):
    db_connection = MagicMock()
    connect_to_database.return_value = db_connection  # 1.
    mock_cursor = MagicMock()
    db_connection.cursor.return_value = mock_cursor   # 2.
    mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = ((1,5,6),)
    self.assertEqual((execute_query(),
                       ((1,5,6),))
```

1. You're patching the symbol `connect_to_database` - that does not mock the call to the function. You need to specify that "when that symbol is called, do this"
2. When mocking function calls, you can't do it like this: `db_connection.cursor().` - you need to make `db_connection.cursor` return a mock, & then specify the `.return_value` for that mock object

Comment: Thanks for the response, But i am not getting the above error, But the mocking isnt working. The return value from the function execute_query() is not what is being mocked. Its returning the real values from database.

Comment: Should the patch target string be execute_query?

Comment: It should be the full path to the connect function. Make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int' I am getting the following error